# Mysql Ranking within grouped results

Tags: mysql

I have read posts that answer how to rank results in mysql, but my question is how to assign ranks within a group

Let me explain with an example

Data:

```
  sem_id | result_month
  --------------------
   1    |1313907325000
   1    |1345529725000
   2    |1329804925000
   2    |1361427325000
   3    |1377065725000
   3    |1440137725000
```

What i am able to achieve with the below query:

```
SELECT @ss := @ss + 1 AS rank, 
       res.sm_id, 
       res.result_month 
FROM   (SELECT sm_id, result_month 
        FROM   xx_table
        GROUP  BY sm_id, 
                  result_month) AS res,(SELECT @ss := 0) AS ss;
```

Current results:

```
  rank | sem_id | result_month 
  ----------------------------
  1   | 1   |1313907325000
  2   | 1   |1345529725000
  3   | 2   |1329804925000
  4   | 2   |1361427325000
  5   | 3   |1377065725000
  6   | 3   |1440137725000
```

What I actually want :

```
  rank | sem_id | result_month 
  ----------------------------
  1   | 1   |1345529725000
  2   | 1   |1313907325000
  1   | 2   |1361427325000
  2   | 2   |1329804925000
  1   | 3   |1440137725000
  2   | 3   |1377065725000
```

In the above results things to observe is **each group is ranked within itself** and **each group is ordered by result_month desc**

Help me on how can i achieve the above results

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where `rank` is coming from?

Comment: Ohh sorry, my bad i updated the question with the proper query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, use another variable to compute group:

```
SELECT @ss := CASE WHEN @grp = sem_id THEN @ss + 1 ELSE 1 END AS rank, sem_id, result_month, @grp := sem_id
FROM   (select * from xx_table ORDER  BY sem_id, result_month DESC) m
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ss := 0, @grp = null) ss
```

See [**demo**](http://rextester.com/ECGIB75458) here.

Comment: Great !! Thanks @Forward